# How to Insert and update data into multiple list in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have three table Customer, Product and Orders
I want to insert data of my customer when he orders a product
means ones my customer data is inserted in customer table his ID should be taken and inserted to orders table with product Id
I am new to SharePoint development if any one could help me with a detailed example.

Comment: 3 tables mean 3 lists?

Comment: http://salnikan.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/inserting-multiple-list-items-at-once-into-a-sharepoint-list/

Comment: No I don't want to insert multiple records at once, what I want is when I created my customer how can I get the Id of my customer and insert it in Orders table with other order details.

Comment: Create an Event Receiver using `ItemAdded` Event, capturing current ID of record and routine to make a cascade insert into another Lists. What do you think about?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the product name of the Product list and customer name of Customer list are unique. Then what you need to do is select a customer and then select multiple products and place the order.

Here you better keep 2 lists to handle orders. one is for order meta data and the other is for product items and each items quantities in the child table. the Order Item list will have a lookup columns to the Order list and the Product list and the Order list need to have a lookup to the Customer list.

1. Get the customer id by customer name.
2. Add a record to the Order list.
3. Loop through all the products in the currently placing order.

3.1 Get the product id of the current product by name and add list item to the Order Items list

Comment: 1-No maybe my customer have same names I want to track only by ID. 2- Please if you could give me a sample example because I am new to SharePoint development.

Comment: Here is for adding item. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467435(v=office.14).aspx and here is for reading items http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms456030(v=office.14).aspx. Those are the wto operations you will need.

Comment: If you could answer my question practically in some blogs according to my problem.

Comment: So do you want me to write the whole code for you?

Comment: If you can help me because I am new to SharePoint Development